# Maven dependency not propagated to dependent project

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have two Maven projects in my Eclipse workspace, `datastore` and `service`.

`datastore` has HSQLDB as a Maven dependency with scope `compile`.

Since `service` depends on `datastore`, I have added `datastore` as a required project for it in **Properties > Java Build Path > Projects**.

However, when I now run `service`, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for the HSQLDB JDBC driver (in one of `datastore`’s classes called from `service`).

If I add HSQLDB as a dependency to `service` everything works as it should—though I understand I should not need this, as Maven dependencies with scope `compile` should get propagated to dependent projects.

Also, I notice the `pom.xml` for `service` contains no reference to `datastore`.

Where’s the error, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Properties > Java Build Path > Projects** is an Eclipse mechanism and will not propagate Maven dependencies. In order for dependency propagation to work as intended, `datastore` needs to be a Maven dependency.

Add `datastore` as a Maven dependency, using the group ID, artifact ID and version from its `pom.xml`. After that, the project can be removed from **Properties > Java Build Path > Projects**.

Comment: If it is not used for compilation, I would recommand also adding this dependency with ```<scope>runtime</scope>```